# Species identification, tree from Ecuador

Tags: botany, species-identification

This tree is recently photographed in Quito, Ecuador. It grows everywhere. I'm new to South American flora, so I'd like to know what the species it is?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your plant appears to be [*Chionanthus pubescens*](http://images.google.com/#q=Chionanthus+pubescens), the pink fringe tree, which is native to Ecuador and Peru. The genus has a [number of species](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=Chionanthus). It belongs to the family [Oleaceae](http://www.theplantlist.org/1.1/browse/A/Oleaceae/), which includes well known plants like jasmine, forsythia, ash trees and olives. I could not find much biological information on the pink fringe tree but [plantlist.org](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/kew-367509) contains a number of links to various databases that may be helpful if you want to dig deeper.